# Error using "Format" double with three decimal

Tags: vba, excel, format

I have a weird behavior using `Format` in my VBA code. I have a double number that should be converted to text and written in a cell. As soon as I use three decimals to be shown the number `1.0076237755` is converted wrongly:

```
thisSheet.Cells(...) = Format(cellValue, "#,##0.000")
```

is showing **1008,000** (German number location with decimal separator ",")

with using only two decimals it somehow works:

```
thisSheet.Cells(...) = Format(cellValue, "#,##0.00")
```

is showing **1,01** (German number location with decimal separator ",")

I have no idea what I'm missing here. I never saw that before and I use `Format` a lot.
Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried something like `Format(CDbl(cellValue), "#,##0.000")`?

Comment: Do you want the output to be 1,008 or 1.008?

Comment: @R3uK, let me check...

Comment: @Alex Weber, 1,008 since I'm using German locale.

Comment: @R3uK, using `CDbl` doesn't work either... Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think this has to do with Excel interpreting the string value and formatting the cell accordingly. So what you could try is adding a single quote before the Format ("'" & Format(...))  to force Excel to display the value as text instead of trying to interpret the value as a number.

Comment: @Tom, thanks Tom. I use a single quote "+" already but with the same effect. Weird...

Comment: @Tom, there will be no large integers. The system has the German locale setting "," for decimal separator and no separator for Thousands. What do you mean with system separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried quite a few possibilities with `Format` but it doesn't seem to work properly on its own.

If you add `thisSheet.Cells(...).NumberFormat = "#,##0.000"`, it will display what you want but you'll still have the whole value stored (in `.Value2`)

So I decided to try with `Round` function, and it does work properly :

```
thisSheet.Cells(...) = Round(CDbl(Replace(Cel, ".", ",")), 3)
thisSheet.Cells(...) = Format(Round(CDbl(Replace(Cel, ".", ",")), 3), "#,##0.000")
```

Comment: I'll try to format the cell instead of the string. I do not want to force the separator behavior. It could be a problem when using a different locale setting.

Comment: I think I found the reason. As soon as a number formated as string is written in a cell the separator behavior could get messed up. This happens because of the string is recognized as a number and converted with a messed up separator behavior. Interessting is when using a combined string like `Format(cellValue, "#,##0.000") & " +" & Format(cellValue, "#,##0.000")` it somehow works. ...

Comment: ... BUT as soon as I use only  `" +" & Format(cellValue, "#,##0.000")` it does not show the number string as wanted. Because the cell reads the string as number again. The best work arround is just using     `" ' "` like: `" '+" & Format(cellValue, "#,##0.000")`. It will write the number as string into the cell.

Comment: @JFS Ok, thx for the explanation and glad you found your solution!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241719(v=vs.60).aspx), it sounds like in VBA, the decimal separator is always a period. You can get around this, using the code below.

```
thisSheet.Cells(...) = Replace(Format(cellValue, "#,##0.000"), ".", ",")
```

Since the decimal separator is now a string, any action to that cell will treat it as if it were a thousands separator, and not a decimal. But this should give you what you want.